# Where does my Spring Boot Config Value come from?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot allows a lot of ways to configure your application and to overwrite existing configuration properties (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

In our application I guess we use every single feature described there (at least twice). Now starting the application (of corse in a container in kubernetes) I have discovered some misconfiguration.

Is there a way to find out where a configuration property comes from? Something providing some output like

```
property "foo":
-> from PropertySource classpath://myFooSource.proproperties = baa
-> from application.properties = baz
-> from environment variable FOO = bar
-> final from command line --foo=ping
```

Comment: Did you check configmaps?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Spring Boot Actuator `/env` endpoint is what you are looking for, given that it returns the current environment properties in your application. You can enable it with `management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true`. You can check more details in the reference documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#env.